# Display time remaining / time estimate in the issue list on an Epic

Tags: jira

In the "Issues in Epic" area I would like to add a column that shows the time remaining estimate, and if possible the time estimate, on each issue. I see the sum of these in the Epic on the right but would love to see them in this list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is very generic. Are you using cloud or server? Out of the box this is not possible. There are plugins such as: [Epic sum up](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213091/epic-sum-up?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) that attempt to add this type of functionality. I would suggest looking at the Atlassian marketplace.

Disclosure: I do not use or have an affiliation to this tool. It is an attempt to point you to a place that may have a viable solution.